# Using Multiple IF NOT EXISTS Statements Inside A Single Query

Tags: sql-server, bulkinsert, not-exists

I am trying to run a multi INSERT Query against MSSQL where I insert a bulk amount of records into the same table.  So my query so far looks like so:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[People] (Code, Name) VALUES(101,'Bob'), (102,'John'), (103,'Jane');
```

I want to elaborate on the Query so that it will only INSERT the record if it doesn't already exist.  I know I can use the following statement:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [dbo].[People] WHERE Code = 101) BEGIN
INSERT INTO [dbo].[People] (Code, Name) VALUES(101,'Bob');
END
```

However, I can only work out how to apply that to a single record.
Is there a way I can run multiple 'IF NOT EXISTS' statements inside a single Query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a couple of ways:

```
insert into [dbo].[People] (Code, Name) 
select x.c, x.n
from
(
    select 101 c, 'Bob' n
    union select 102 c, 'Rob' n
) x
where c in (select code from [dbo].[People])
```

--or

```
insert into [dbo].[People] (Code, Name) 
select x.c, x.n
from
(
    select 101 c, 'Bob' n
    union select 102 c, 'Rob' n
) x
where exists (select top 1 1 from [dbo].[People] p where p.code = x.c)
```

Or if you want to get more advanced, you could look into the `merge` statement, which allows you to perform multiple operations based on a variety of conditions:

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/06/08/sql-server-merge-operations-insert-update-delete-in-single-execution/

```
merge [dbo].[People] as target
using 
(
    select 101 c, 'Bob' n
    union select 102 c, 'Rob' n
) as source
on source.c = target.code
when not matched by source then
insert(code,name) values (c, n);
```

However, for your use case `merge` is probably overly complicated.  That statement becomes useful when you want to do additional operations, such as update rows that exist but insert new ones where they don't.

Comment: Thanks John.  I am trying to get my head around the MERGE statement but I can't see how that works for varying SELECT statements within the same table. The MERGE looks like the right way to go, but his example merges two tables together.  I need to loop through a single table checking the Code on each row.  Are you able to elaborate on that example?

Comment: Sure - updated with an example - however `merge` is beyond your stated requirement; I only mentioned it in case you had a more complex need but weren't aware of that statement.

Comment: Okay, looks like the MERGE won't be suitable so going to go with your first example.  Just one question though: for my example I tried to keep it simple using two fields (Code and Name), however, If I was wanting to insert 20 fields for each record, but only check if the ID was present where would I place the other data as I'm getting the following error and your example uses 3 different SELECT statements: "The select list for the INSERT statement contains fewer items than the insert list. The number of SELECT values must match the number of INSERT columns"

Comment: On the first line of the insert statement I name the columns I wish to insert into (`Code, Name`).  On the second line I list the columns I wish to put into those fields `x.c, x.n`.  Those fields have to match (the number of columns selected and the order they're named in).  Finally the unioned subquery which provides the data to be inserted (`select 101 c, 'Bob' n`...) has to provide the values in order for them to be available to be inserted.

Comment: Thankyou for your time and assistance with helping me with this.